# How do I make a textbox take only numeric characters using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, plugins, numeric

I need to make a textbox that only allows numeric characters.  I've looked through several numeric plugins and can't find one that I like.  I'm looking for either a plugin recommendation with the associated URL or syntax showing how to get started on making my own plugin.

Comment: The [masked input plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) should do exactly what you need.

Comment: Check this nice article: [Restricting Input in HTML Textboxes to Numeric Values](http://west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/1006040.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#testinput").keypress(function(e){
  if (isNaN(String.fromCharCode(e.which))){
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: cool one.. Helps me a lot. Why these guys going back to the plugins..!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can start by implementing the function with JQuery and then integrate it into a (configurable) plugin.

To handle textbox input you should intercept keydown event on textbox and then prevent the input if it's not allowed.

To write a plugin you can start from here:
http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/a-plugin-development-pattern
http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/making-a-jquery-plugin-truly-customizable